# TypeScript giving error on optional spread property

Tags: typescript

I got the following code:

```
type MakeStyleConfig = {
  updateConfig?: {
    prevProps: Record<string, unknown>
    styledProps: string[]
  }
  [K: string]: unknown
}
type MakeStyles = (config?: MakeStyleConfig) => void

const makeStyles : MakeStyles = (config) => console.log(config)

let updateConfig: MakeStyleConfig | undefined
if (3/4 > -2) {
  updateConfig = {
    prevProps: {a:3},
    styledProps: ['size', 'shape']
  }
}
const state = {loaded: false}

// Why is this not working?
makeStyles({updateConfig: updateConfig, ...state})
//          ^^^^^^^^^^^^ this is marked as error by TSC

// This works OK as I expected:
makeStyles({updateConfig: {prevProps:{a:3}, styledProps:["s"], ...state}})
```

Why is the code marked as an error by TypeScript (v4.2.3)? It has the correct type and fields. The error is also pretty cryptic:

```
Type 'MakeStyleConfig | undefined' is not assignable to type '{ prevProps: Record<string, unknown>; styledProps: string[]; } | undefined'.
  Type 'MakeStyleConfig' is missing the following properties from type '{ prevProps: Record<string, unknown>; styledProps: string[]; }': prevProps, styledProps
```

Here is [a link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.3#code/C4TwDgpgBAsghgawgZVAGwgYQPYDsBmAlgOZQC8UA3gFBRQCuYAJnMFnkcQPwBcVtdKGABOEAG4AFYdjABnPgCUIAY2zCmAHlnBhhXMQA0DXAlzYA7rgB8AutpAYmUmfKjbd%20gNoBdAQF8BTwBpPnc9Ym8%20ehMzS2oA0EhYRBR0CFlyKAAKVQISXmSkVAd2POIASnIrKDFsQiZqalztKABbFOKMDL54IrSMihyOEkqyaubsDAA6NGxiIbLyxoxgBmZWUs4ejrScMqgAH2MmCCJcCAbCfGyAZgB6ABYoaoBaACZKmjpGFjY9zkyX0EInEzjkfEocB4Nz8BlsbjSTmk4KgngA5LJCAAvCBoowYgAWcEgaN8dACAWaq20G0BszgJyYfHwcDQsggAWodzuUAA6gSQFBCBlgAThVAzKtzGoEOEuNR2n0SrIspQfht-iQous-sNDFApoaaWw-EtuYILYIAHo2212m1QUXi8XtYRIJhQOAZCDCaTCKAAI0FABVkJhGubg2KMtK3RkAPJBT0ZACSUAgAA9IMo2EyFTtlar1bqyhCQZJkfJIdDYQiSkiXDxPAAiWTN7xGQ1TY0c01AA) for the TS playground

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to set `updateConfig` which is of type `MakeStyleConfig` to `MakeStyleConfig.updateConfig` which is of type

```js
{
    prevProps: Record<string, unknown>,
    styledProps: string[]
}
```

The two are clearly not of the same type.

You should probably define a type which you can reuse for the `updateConfig` field on your `MakeStyleConfig` object, and change

```js
let updateConfig: MakeStyleConfig | undefined
```

to be of that new type.

Example:

```js
type UpdateConfig = {prevProps: Record<string, unknown>; styledProps: string[];}
type MakeStyleConfig = {
  updateConfig?: UpdateConfig | undefined
  [K: string]: unknown
}

// ...

let updateConfig: UpdateConfig | undefined;

// ...

makeStyles({updateConfig, ...state}) // this should now work
```

Comment: my question was why is it marked as an error. Casting is not a nice solution, it could mask an underlying issue.

Comment: @sydd I've amended my answer as I initially misread your question.

Comment: You are right, I mixed up the object nesting. Thanks for the help!